# Is it possible to add formatting within Ui alert/prompt? Specifically line breaks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a list of variables with a Ui alert/prompt box.  Is this possible?

I've tried searching the internet for fixes with no luck. Also tried (\n) and br, also with no luck.

```
function Handover(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var buttons = ui.ButtonSet.OK
  var LiDCO = ss.getRange("Tech Dashboard!O3:O11").getValues();
  var filter = ss.getRange("Tech Dashboard!M3:M11").getValues();
  var paedfilters = ss.getRange("Tech Dashboard!Q3:Q6").getValues();
  var nox = ss.getRange("Tech Dashboard!Q8:Q11").getValues();

  var handover = ui.alert('Please check the equipment in beds: ' 
                          + 'LiDCOs: '+ LiDCO  
                          + 'Filters: '+ filter 
                          + 'Paed Filters: '+ paedfilters 
                          + 'Nitric: '+ nox 
                          + ' and update the Dashboard.', buttons)
  }
```

I expected the Ui box to list the 4 variables on separate lines but the result just had one long string.

Comment: Alerts don't accept HTML. Use a modal dialog. Review documentation.

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch I know how to create a Modal Dialog but not how to include information from my sheet. Is there a link you know where i could learn how to code that into HTML?

Comment: Yes, the htmlservice documentation explicitly addresses communication between the client (the dialog) and the server (apps script + your sheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing the alert using the code below worked for me. You can insert carriage-return/line feeds using the `\r\n` sequence like this:

```
function showAlerts() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var buttons = ui.ButtonSet.OK
  var handover = ui.alert('Please check the equipment in beds: ' 
                          + '\r\nLiDCOs: '+ 12  
                          + '\r\nFilters: '+ 15 
                          + '\r\nPaed Filters: '+ 234
                          + '\r\nNitric: '+ 63 
                          + '\r\nand update the Dashboard.', buttons)
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Saves me trying to learn HTML stuff! Any idea how to ignore blank cells in the getRange function i have used?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title) which uses html to format text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).